# Reusable way to assign a bi-directional record to another

Tags: vhdl

I am using the UVVM AXI-Stream VVC. It defines the AxiStream interface as a record type, shortened in this question for brevity.

So, given this record type that contains signals going in both directions

```
  type t_axistream_if is record
    tdata  : std_logic_vector;  -- Going in
    tvalid : std_logic;         -- Going in
    tready : std_logic;         -- Going out
  end record;
```

I want a re-usable method that can reorder the bytes in `tdata` and connect two instances of this record to each other.

This is the functionality that I am looking for. The following VHDL is functional:

```
   -- dutInput and axisMasterIf are constrained instances of the record.
   dutInput.tData      <= reverseBytes(axisMasterIf.tData);
   dutInput.tValid     <= axisMasterIf.tValid;
   axisMasterIf.tReady <= dutInput.tReady;
```

What i want is something like this (because the record is much larger):

```
   dutInput            <= reverse(axisMasterIf);
   axisMasterIf.tReady <= dutInput.tReady; 
   -- or using a procedure
   -- reverse(axisMasterIf, dutInput)
```

When using procedures it doesn't seem like the signals are continuously assigned. When using functions i struggle with not assigning dutInput.tReady.

Here is a few, non-working, attempts:

```
   -- If I set outIf <= reverse(inIf) this function will drive the
   -- TReady-signal and I will get U due to multiple drivers.
   -- When I  set TReady as open, it just doesn't compile. 
   function reverse(inIf : t_axistream_if) return t_axistream_if is
   begin
      return (
         tData  => reverseBytes(inIf.tData),
         tValid => inIf.tValid,
         tReady => open -- This doesn't compile.
      );
   end function;


   -- This compiles, but the signals don't seem to become continually assigned when the procedure is called from within a process.
   procedure reverse(
      signal inIf  : inout t_axistream_if;
      signal outIf : inout t_axistream_if
   ) is
   begin
      outIf.tData  <= reverseBytes(inIf.tData);
      outIf.tValid <= inIf.tValid;

      inIf.tReady <= outIf.tReady;
   end procedure;
```

The code does not need to be synthesizable. I'm using VHDL2008.

Comment: What counts as "not working" ? can you provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) ? Why are you trying to drive an axi interface in two directions? AXI is uni-directional

Comment: I tried to add some more explanations. This is AXI-Stream, but AXI also has ready-signalling. Ready will always be going in the direction opposite of the rest of the bus. It isn't always helpful to put both things in the same record but that's beside the point; the interface is given (by UVVM) and I need to work around it. I can create a MCVE, but not right now.

Comment: without the context of how the reverse procedure is used, its difficult to give an answer.

Comment: A VHDL implementation can't peer further into a subprogram than the parameter list to identify drivers, a record parameter will have drivers for all elements. (A process declarative item procedure can drive signals not in it's parameter list, but doesn't make allow reuse).  Without a [mcve] reuse other than function `reverseBytes` can't be seen. Your readers might take it you're talking about different types of endpoint operations or functionality.

Answer (score -2):

With respect to this block:

> ```
>    -- This compiles, but the signals don't seem to become continually assigned when the procedure is called from within a process.
>    procedure reverse(
>       signal inIf  : inout t_axistream_if;
>       signal outIf : inout t_axistream_if
>    ) is
>    begin
>       outIf.tData  <= reverseBytes(inIf.tData);
>       outIf.tValid <= inIf.tValid;
>
>       inIf.tReady <= outIf.tReady;
>    end procedure;
> ```

... specifically:

> *... but the signals don't seem to become **continually assigned** when the procedure is called from within a process*

All assignments in a (clocked) process turn into flip-flops.  Using your procedure `reverse` in a process will change the timing of the signals by adding an extra clock cycle of delay.  This is the expected behaviour.

However, that is likely not what you want.  You will want to use the procedure outside any process to ensure it is pass-through without any delay.

Comment: The OP never mentioned a clocked process, and specifically said it is not for synthesis. And given the UVVM mention this is likely in a procedural testbench process. But these are all guesses as there is no MCVE.